# Setting Application Specific Max Heap Size for the Android Dalvik VM

Tags: android, heap-memory, dalvik

Is it possible to set an application-specific max heap size (the dalvik.vm.heapsize property) instead of using the same maximum heapsize for all VM's running on an Android device? I know I can set a new dalvik heapsize by modifying the device's AndroidRuntime.cpp as root, but based on what I have read, because Android only initializes the VM once and then forks subsequent VM instances all VM's running on the device have the same dalvik.vm.heapsize property. Am I understanding this correctly, and is there any way around it?

Comment: Are you working as root? I don;t think there is any easy solution unless you want to messup with dalvik code.

Comment: Yes, I'm working as root and can modify the dalvik code. My thought was to replace the VM forking in dalvik with fork+exec so I could reinitialize the heapsize property, but I do not know what sort of performance disadvantages this will cause. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only built-in way to change heap size of an app is by setting `android:largeHeap="true"` in the Manifest.xml. This will generally increase heap size from 48 to 128.

Keep in mind this approach will only work on 3.0+ devices.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is the heap size allocated using largeHeap device specific?

I'm targeting API level 10 so I guess this is not an option for me.

Comment: Yes the heap size is ultimately decided by the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using this App u can increase Heap memomry of required Application

http://www.freeware4android.net/lg-c660-optimus-pro-device-2140/hacks-tweaks-tag/vm-heap-tool-download-27936.html

keep in mind that to use this app u need to **root** your device, use **SuperOneClick** App to root ur device.. Click below link for Reference

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/root-android-phone-superoneclick-2/