# dalvik doesn't seem to be growing the heap

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, dalvik

I have an instance of dalvik running:

```
/system/bin/dalvikvm ... -Xmx100m ...
```

With the memmap looking like:

```
b01f6000-b05b7000 rwxp 00000000 00:04 4635       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
b05b7000-b65f6000 ---p 003c1000 00:04 4635       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
```

But I'm getting a ton of these messages since GC is running all the time:

```
<dalvikvm> GC_CONCURRENT freed 1880K, 52% free 1882K/3843K, paused 5ms+9ms
<dalvikvm> GC_CONCURRENT freed 1882K, 52% free 1881K/3843K, paused 5ms+9ms
<dalvikvm> GC_CONCURRENT freed 1881K, 52% free 1881K/3843K, paused 6ms+9ms
<dalvikvm> GC_CONCURRENT freed 1880K, 52% free 1882K/3843K, paused 5ms+8ms
<dalvikvm> GC_CONCURRENT freed 1882K, 52% free 1881K/3843K, paused 6ms+9ms
<dalvikvm> GC_CONCURRENT freed 1880K, 52% free 1882K/3843K, paused 5ms+9ms
<dalvikvm> GC_CONCURRENT freed 1882K, 52% free 1881K/3843K, paused 6ms+9ms
```

There is plenty of free memory:

```
MemFree:          496056 kB
```

What I'm wondering is why isn't the heap growing more it seems stuck at 4MB... ?

btw, I really *do* need 100MB, and actually that is just a small starting point...

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Dalvik VM's policy is to keep the heap size as small as possible.  Since it's freeing up 1.8MB every time it collects, it's probably rather proud of itself.

If you're seeing tons of these messages, it just means you're allocating and discarding a lot of memory, and the activity is normal.  Anything you can do to reduce the memory churn would help here.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about Dalvik, but a normal JVM can be configured via `-Xmx100M` to eat 100 MB. IIUYC you have enough memory free so there's no need to run GC. OTOH, the GC works efficient so there's no need to claim more memory. As mobile phones are rather constrained devices, it doesn't surprise me that Dalvik runs conservatively.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557219/setting-application-specific-max-heap-size-for-the-android-dalvik-vm) shows how to grow the heap.